# Can't return a result set in the given context

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysqli, multi-select

When ever I try to call store procedure in mysql that sends back a result set, it keeps saying me that "can't return a result set in the given context".

I've google it and some said it's mysql bug, some said you should change your mysqli driver and ....

Situation :

Using mysqli driver Client API library version  5.0.51a , PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6, Using Zend 1.9 RC 1 Mysqli adapter.

What should I do!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the solution to your problem, but what about trying with a more recent version of PHP ?

PHP 5.2.4 is definitly quite old -- so, if it's a bug in PHP's mysqli driver, it might have been corrected since...

Actually, after a quick search, it seems a problem like the one you are witnessing has been introduced between PHP 5.2.3 and PHP 5.2.4 (and was still here in PHP 5.2.5).

See [bug #42548 : PROCEDURE xxx can't return a result set in the given context (works in 5.2.3!!)](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42548)

Are you able to test with something like PHP 5.2.9 or 5.2.10 ?

I know these are not provided by Ubuntu, even in the last Ubuntu stable version :-( You might have to compile from sources :-(

---

Yet another idea would be to try mith PDO_MySql adapter : maybe it would work with that one ?

It might be possible to change Adapter without causing too much trouble / without taking hours to test ?

---

As you are working with Zend Framework 1.9, here's another post that might interest you, and might be easier to test : [stored procedure error after upgrade to 1.8](http://www.nabble.com/stored-procedure-error-after-upgrade-to-1.8-tt23872061.html#a23872061)

An easy solution to try that would be to go back to Zend Framework 1.7 ; would it be possible for you, just to test ?

Anyway... Good luck !

And, if you find the solution, don't forget to indicate what the problem was, and how you solved it ;-)

Comment: Could this problem come back in 5.2.17? I'm getting the same error but CentOS PHP later version.

Comment: Probably some other issue as I found similar problem on version 5.3.1 using xammp and windows

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to upgrade your php, I've just upgraded mine to 5.3.0, and it's works likes Candy!

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution you choose :-)
(Just beware : using PHP 5.3 might lead to other troubles elsewhere in your code, as it bring lots of new stuff ^^ )

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently on a contract.  The client was using a codebase on windoze and php 5.2.6 and my installation was linux and php 5.3.1  Whatever we did, they wouldn't co-operate so in the end they gave me a windoze vista machine and we installed php 5.2.6 and off we went.  Moral of the story: version matching counts.  Weird cus I never had this ever before in any other job.  But hey, you can't know everything.  Very definitely not a MySql issue, just PHP.

Comment: I was flummoxed to get this problem on PHP 5.2.6 when trying to deploy a system developed on a PHP 5.3 development server. So I'll have to upgrade. Note that there are [backward incompability issues](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php).

Comment: @Gruber, ? There're always backward incompat issues. What's so special about those versions?

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly with PHP 5.2.10 as well.

From an earlier version, I've successfully used mysqli::multi_query to call a problematic procedure and get the right results.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but for those still working with 5.2.4 and getting this error, you may consider creating a new mysql PDO object to work around this problem.

I still use 5.2.4 on my dev server to ensure backward compatibility for the WordPress plugins I develop.

Below is a wrapper around procedural calls that I use to successfully call procedures in both 5.2.4 (run on my dev server) , which would normally give me the error, and my production server (which runs a newer version that doesn't give the error) .

Its WordPress specific, but it wouldn't be difficult to modify it using straight php.

```
/*
* Need to cache connection so we don't keep creating connections till we hit max.
*/

private $_dbhCache=null; 

/**
     * mySQL Call Proc
     *
     * Provides a wrapper around calling a mySQL stored procedure to ensure against a 5.2.4 bug that 
     * causes procedure calls to fail.
     * Error:'can't return a result set in the given context'
     * 
     * references:
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context
     * http://php.net/pdo_mysql#69592  //i got empty result set but pointed me in the right direction
     * http://php.net/pdo_mysql#80306 //this worked, but returned 0-indexed and assoc, i edited it so it only returns assoc mimicking $wpdb->get_results(
     * http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
     * http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php explains about FETCH_ASSOC
     * 
     * @param string $proc The mySQL stored procedure string, including paramaters, but without the call statement. e.g.: "my_procedure_name('my_paramater')"; 
     * @return string The results of the procedure call
     */
    public function mySQLCallProc( $proc ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "call $proc";

        try {

            /*
             * Attempt to call the procedure normally.
             * 
             */

            $query_result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

            /*
             * Check for a database error
             * and throw an exception if one is found.
             * We can then attempt it again using a workaround.
             */

          if ( $wpdb->last_error !== '' ) { 



                throw new Exception( 'Database Error While Calling Procedure' );
}

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            try {

                /*
                 * Create a PDO Object for the connection
                 */
  if ( is_null($this->_dbhCache)) {
                    $dbh = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';port=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ) );
 $this->_dbhCache=$dbh ;            
}else{
     $dbh = $this->_dbhCache;
}
                /*
                 * Prepare and call the procedure.
                 */
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "call $proc" );

                $stmt->execute();

                /*
                 *  fetch all rows into an associative array.
                 */

                $query_result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); //FETCH_ASSOC gets results as an assoc array. without it, you'll receive both assoc and 0-indexed array





    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

                    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();

    }


    }

        return ($query_result);


    }
```