# MySQL Stored Procedures not working with SELECT (basic question)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1312

I am using a platform (perfectforms) that requires me to use stored procedures for most of my queries, and having never used stored procedures, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  The following statement executes without error:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_db.test_proc//
CREATE PROCEDURE test_db.test_proc() SELECT 'foo'; //
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I try to call it using:

```
CALL test_proc();
```

I get the following error:

```
#1312 - PROCEDURE test_db.test_proc can't return a result set in the given context
```

I am executing these statements from within phpmyadmin 3.2.4, PHP Version 5.2.12 and the mysql server version is 5.0.89-community.

When I write a stored procedure that returns a parameter, and then select it, things work fine (e.g.):

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_db.get_sum//
CREATE PROCEDURE test_db.get_sum(out total int)
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(field1) INTO total FROM test_db.test_table;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

works fine, and when I call it:

```
CALL get_sum(@t); SELECT @t;
```

I get the sum no problem.

Ultimately, what I need to do is have a fancy SELECT statement wrapped up in a stored procedure, so I can call it, and return multiple rows of multiple fields.  For now I'm just trying to get *any* select working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say `CALL myproc();` I assume you mean `CALL test_proc();`?

Comment: Yes - sorry that was a type-o.  Is there any way for me to edit that?

Comment: Yea, I think you should be able to edit your own posts. (Should be a edit link somewhere.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out.  This is not a bug with PHP (though it used to be) - it's a bug in some versions of phpmyadmin.  The same bug intermittently reappears and is then fixed in various subversions (see above):

```
#1312 - PROCEDURE [name] can't return a result set in the given context
```

This behavior appears limited to ***SELECT statements within stored procedures inside phpmyadmin***.

Using a client like MySQL Workbench works around the problem (or you could upgrade phpmyadmin, but that's a pain if you're on a shared server like I am).

Anyway, thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: "Solved" the problem for me too - that is, I can reproduce the bug using phpmyadmin, and it doesn't appear in the mysql CLI client, nor the PHP application itself.

Comment: @tdammers - hey thanks for the validation.  Sometimes when all the smart programmers on this board tell me I'm crazy, I start to think that I am.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php version to see if this is a reported bug (see [here](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42548)).

See this post:
[Can't return a result set in the given context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context)

Comment: I did see that post.  My PHP version is PHP Version 5.2.12, which is allegedly before that bug appears.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is centered around a bug dealing with PHP and SELECT within a stored procedure/routine. One possible work around is to use the **[SELECT... INTO](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/mysql-refman/stored-procedures.html)** inside of the stored procedure to bring the result down to one variable. This worked in some [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641926/call-stored-procedure-using-php) that I read.

```
   SELECT * FROM category INTO c;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I execute the following:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_db.test_proc//
CREATE PROCEDURE test_db.test_proc() SELECT 'foo'; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Followed by

```
CALL test_db.test_proc();
```

I shows me a result set like:

```
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.1, MySQL 5.1.41 with phpMyAdmin 3.2.4.

Perhaps you just misspelled your procedure name?
Or could there be a problem with your PHP or MySQL installations? (Perhaps a bug. Have you tried updating to the latest versions?)

Comment: I checked the names.  I tested it on another local server.  This one is running PHP Version 5.2.9, MySQL 5.1.33-community, and phpmyadmin 3.1.3.1.  According to the bug reports, that config should not have a problem.

However, still the same error:
#1312 - PROCEDURE test_db.test_proc can't return a result set in the given context