# How do I write an SP in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

How do I write a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin you can create the stored procedure in the SQL window.

You may have to set the delimieter to something like "$$" instead of the default ";". You can change this from the bottom of the SQL window.

[image: Stored Procedure in phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Thanks ...now my sp excuting without Error...
How to call the my sp in phpmyadmin,
i did somthing like 

call productpricing();

and then i hit the GO button , suddenly page get refreshed, that's it...nothing happen....

Comment: To call the stored procedure, simply type `CALL mySproc();` in the SQL window and then hit the GO button.

Comment: I GOT THIS ERROR 

#1312 - PROCEDURE ukatn_qa.show_my_country can't return a result set in the given context

Comment: Unfortunately this is bug in older versions of phpMyAdmin. It looks like you need to upgrade your phpMyAdmin. Check out the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/. This bug effects only phpMyAdmin. You would still be able to call the stored procedure from anywhere else (from php, or from the MySql CLI).

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the internets:

> The answer is yes and no. Phpmyadmin
>   has no tools for creating stored
>   procedures but you can enter in SQL
>   using it and in that way create them.
>
> (Note I don't believe versions prior
>   to MySQL 5 supported stored
>   procedures.)

Comment: assume if i am not getting any out put then ..how to i cross check...assume if i forgot to put semicolon , then the program is error on know..so how i find these sort of  error...where i find

Comment: my problem not fixed...still search solution

Comment: What you are asking is "If there is an error, how do I find it?" - There is no short answer to this.