# Trouble creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm messing around with stored procedures for the first time, but can't even create a simple select! I'm using phpMyAdmin and this is my SQL:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE test_select() 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 10; 
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

After submitting that, my localhost does some thinking for a loooong time and eventually loads a page with no content called /phpmyadmin/import.php. After reloading phpMyAdmin and trying to invoke the procedure:

```
CALL test_select();
```

I get a "PROCEDURE doesn't exist" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the delimiter field of phpMyAdmin, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Trouble creating stored procedure]

Simply put the following in the query window:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_select() 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 10; 
END
```

---

In addition note that there is bug in some older versions of phpMyAdmin, which can cause an error when you call stored procedures that contain `SELECT` statements from phpMyAdmin.

You may want to check out the following posts for further reading:

- [MySQL Stored Procedures not working with SELECT (basic question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/mysql-stored-procedures-not-working-with-select-basic-question/2437024#2437024)
- [How do I write an SP in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454071/how-do-i-write-an-sp-in-phpmyadmin-mysql/2498437#2498437)

This bug effects only phpMyAdmin, and you would still be able to call the stored procedure from anywhere else.

Comment: The problem was actually my use of DELIMITER // directly in the query when I should have been using phpMyAdmin's UI to change the delimiter. Your second link gave me the answer though, so +1. As it happens I've got phpMyAdmin bug too. BAH!