# Why Am I Getting MySQL Error #1312 when Using a Simple Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1312

I'm trying to learn how to use MySQL stored procedures. MySQL accepted my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SimpleProc()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM myTable;
   END
```

(In phpMyAdmin, I set // for delimiter. The real version has the name of an actual table instead of myTable.).

But, when I call the procedure with `CALL SimpleProc();`, I get error "#1312 - PROCEDURE mydb.SimpleProc can't return a result set in the given context".

I read that some versions of php or phpMyAdmin won't work with stored procedures.

I'm using a localhost running on a Mac with MAMP 1.9. I've got MySQL 5.1.44, PHP 5.2.13 & 5.3.2, phpMyAdmin 3.2.5. Does anyone know if stored procedures will work with my set-up? Am I doing something incorrectly? Any advice?

Shout out to the Big Red for a triple overtime victory in Lax.

Thanks, 
Laxmidi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there seems to be a bug in some older versions of phpMyAdmin, which can cause the 1312 error you are getting. This can happen when calling stored procedures that contain `SELECT` statements from phpMyAdmin.

You may want to check out the following posts for further reading:

- [MySQL Stored Procedures not working with SELECT (basic question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/mysql-stored-procedures-not-working-with-select-basic-question/2437024#2437024)
- [How do I write an SP in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454071/how-do-i-write-an-sp-in-phpmyadmin-mysql/2498437#2498437) (comments)

This bug effects only phpMyAdmin, and you would still be able to call the stored procedure from anywhere else.

Comment: Hey Daniel,

Thank you for the interesting info. It looks like other folks running roughly my setup had the same problems.

Now, I have to figure out how to call a mysql stored procedure from php.

Again, thanks for the very useful info. 

-Laxmidi