# MySQL server stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, select, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I am having some trouble with creating a Stored Procedure for a MySQL database.

Here is a Select statement that works:

```
use canningi_db_person_cdtest;
SELECT *
FROM pet
WHERE name = 'Puffball';
```

Here is my Stored Procedure that does not work:

```
use canningi_db_person_cdtest;
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllPets() 
BEGIN 
SELECT *
FROM pet
WHERE name = 'Puffball'; 
END
```

I am getting the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

How can I get this working?

**EDIT**

How do I call this Stored Procedure? I have tried this with no result:

```
use canningi_db_person_cdtest;
CALL GetAllPets();
```

This is the error:

```
#1312 - PROCEDURE canningi_db_person_cdtest.GetAllPets can't return a result set in the given context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delimiter to end your procedure. Example:

```
use canningi_db_person_cdtest;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllPets() 
BEGIN 
    SELECT *
    FROM pet
    WHERE name = 'Puffball'; 
END//
```

If you need more information, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Thanks rcs. Can you have a look at my edit on calling the Stored Procedure?

Comment: The `CALL GetAllPets();` should work fine. How is it possible to have error : `EXEC GetAllPets()`? Did you type EXEC instead of CALL?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong error message. I have updated the post.

Comment: Are you executing the `CALL` statement in the mysql directly (e.g. through mysql workbench), or are you calling it from your application? Some users reported issue with PHP as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context.

Comment: I am executing the CALL statement from phpMyAdmin that is part of cPanel. Will this not work?

Comment: There has been issues with phpMyAdmin as well. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/mysql-stored-procedures-not-working-with-select-basic-question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842263/why-am-i-getting-mysql-error-1312-when-using-a-simple-stored-procedure. Sometimes the error is not about the syntax, but about the software that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, since you have only one statement in your procedure, you don't need to change `DELIMITER` nor use `BEGIN...END` block.

You procedure might look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllPets() 
  SELECT *
    FROM pet
   WHERE name = 'Puffball';
```

And use it like this

```
CALL GetAllPets();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21c01c/1)** demo