# Go MySQL stored procedure cannot return result set

Tags: mysql, go

If I run the below code, but replace the 'CALL' with `"SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1"` I get back a user. If I switch to calling the stored procedure I keep getting this error:

```
panic: Error 1312: PROCEDURE MobiFit_Dev.User_ByEmail can't return a result set in the given context [recovered]
    panic: Error 1312: PROCEDURE MobiFit_Dev.User_ByEmail can't return a result set in the given context
```

How do I call my SP?

Here is my SP:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `MobiFit_Dev`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `User_ByEmail`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_ByEmail`(pEmail VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        `User` 
    WHERE `Email` = pEmail ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

package entities

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "mobifit/db"
    // "time"
)

const (
    Male   = "Male"
    Female = "Female"
)

type User struct {
    Id             sql.NullInt64
    Email          sql.NullString
    HashedPassword sql.NullString
    RoleId         sql.NullInt64
    FirstName      sql.NullString
    LastName       sql.NullString
    Gender         sql.NullString
    DateOfBirth    mysql.NullTime
    Height         sql.NullFloat64
    CurrentWeight  sql.NullFloat64
    CreatedAt      mysql.NullTime
    ConfirmedAt    mysql.NullTime
    LastActivityAt mysql.NullTime
    DeletedAt      mysql.NullTime
}

func UserByEmail(email string) *User {
    db := db.DB()
    u := new(User)
    rows, err := db.Query("CALL User_ByEmail(?)", email) << A SELECT *... works but this doesn't

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(rows.Columns())

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(
            &u.Id,
            &u.Email,
            &u.HashedPassword,
            &u.RoleId,
            &u.FirstName,
            &u.LastName,
            &u.Gender,
            &u.DateOfBirth,
            &u.Height,
            &u.CurrentWeight,
            &u.CreatedAt,
            &u.ConfirmedAt,
            &u.LastActivityAt,
            &u.DeletedAt); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u)
    return u
}
```

Comment: How do you call the procedure? `CALL MobiFit.User_ByEmail('email@domain.com')`?

Comment: Yep, that is how you call it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With MySQL you cannot call stored procedures currently, and nor can you execute multiple statements at once apparently.

http://go-database-sql.org/surprises.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using single qoutes.

LIKE THIS

```
CALL User_ByEmail('?');
```

When input parameter is of type `VARCHAR`, then you should Always use single quotes around the value.

Comment: OK, I did that I now get ```panic: sql: statement expects 0 inputs; got 1 [recovered]
 panic: sql: statement expects 0 inputs; got 1```

Comment: Can you add the '' in the `, Email` variable? Can you try to determine what the final syntax is?

Comment: I switched the call to rows, err := db.Query("CALL User_ByEmail('lee@g.com')")
 and now I gt the original error

Comment: Seems to me this is not a MySQL problem. Does this relate to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842263/why-am-i-getting-mysql-error-1312-when-using-a-simple-stored-procedure

Comment: I guess there must be a bug with the driver.