# How to create a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created the following stored procedure in mysql...

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMember(IN in_memberID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Members
    WHERE MemberID = in_memberID;
END//



$result = mysql_query("CALL GetMember(".$memberID.")") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Name'] . "</br>";
}
```

But when I call it from php it returns all records in the Members table, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
When I try to call the query within phpmyadmin I get this error

```
CALL GetMember(1);

#1312 - PROCEDURE myDb.GetMember can't return a result set in the given context
```

Comment: Maybe change the IN var to in_memberId to avoid confusion?

Comment: I agree with @ethrbunny.  I think its confusing the procedure.

Comment: @MelvinProtacio I've added to php.

Comment: Can you call it from the mysql cmd line? Its looks pretty straight-forward.

Comment: can you check if $memberID is not null prior to calling the sp?

Comment: @MelvinProtacio I dont think that is the issue, I get the same result even If I pass in a constant

Comment: can you try changing `in_memberID` to `@in_memberID` and see if it works?

Comment: @MelvinProtacio I get an error if I try to use @ in front of in_memberID;

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/mysql-stored-procedures-not-working-with-select-basic-question/2437024#2437024.  The `1312` error may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454071/how-do-i-write-an-sp-in-phpmyadmin-mysql/2498437#2498437  There is nothing "wrong" with your SP the way it is, but you may want to try changing the delimiter.  Also, if you haven't already, verify that the MemberIDs are truly unique.  If they aren't, you could get multiple results like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

what version of PHP?

PHP 5.2.3 and PHP 5.2.4 have a bug with procedures:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42548

Answer (score 0):

```
use Database_Name;

DELIMETER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Proc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc()
       BEGIN
               DECLARE x INT;
               SET x = 1;
               WHILE x <= 110000 DO
                   INSERT INTO Table_Name (word, mean) VALUES ('a', 'a mean');
                   SET x = x + 1;
               END WHILE;
       END$$

DELIMITER ;
```