# Difficulty in writing Stored Procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The code my Stored Procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_sait_inf(IN name TEXT,IN title TEXT,IN link TEXT)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO sait_inf(sait_name,sait_title,sait_link) VALUES (name,title,link);

END
```

But the error is:

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use  near '' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

- > If you use the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

  The same is true of phpMyAdmin.
- > To redefine the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) delimiter, use the `delimiter` command.

  Not all versions of phpMyAdmin recognise the `delimiter` command; instead, one can use the `Delimiter` input box beneath the SQL input box: see [How do I write an SP in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2498437)
- > The following is an example of a function that takes a parameter, performs an operation using an SQL function, and returns the result. In this case, it is unnecessary to use `delimiter` because the function definition contains no internal `;` statement delimiters:
  >
  > ```
  > mysql> CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
  > mysql> RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
  >     -> RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  > ```

  In your case, you can remove the [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) compound statement block and avoid the need to change delimiter.

Comment: If the BEGIN ... END command to delete the php later when two or more SP SP calls only the first works