# Trigger syntax error in phpmyadmin version 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.1

**SQL Query -**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `credentials` (`UserId`,`Password`,`UserType`,`Status`) 
            VALUES (NEW.UserId,NEW.Password,'2',NEW.Status);
    END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Error -

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Need help... thanks in advance :)..

Comment: @krishna its trigger so how can defined NEW?

Comment: i think you are taking  values from table right ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628238.

Comment: @eggyal please can you help me to resolve this error? I got new error like - "#1142 - TRIGGER command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'user'" when i was removed BEGIN... END

Comment: Sounds like your database user doesn't have permission to create a trigger.  Suggest you request permission from your database administrator.

Comment: @eggyal you mean Privileges issue?

Comment: Are you using the phpMyAdmin "Add trigger" link or just typing SQL statements in to the SQL tab?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch SQL Tab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case you can use this statement -

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW
 INSERT INTO `credentials` (`UserId`,`Password`,`UserType`,`Status`) VALUES (NEW.UserId,NEW.Password,'2',NEW.Status);
```

[What is the DELIMITER in MySQL and what it’s used for.](http://buysql.com/mysql/42-delimiter-mysql.html)

Comment: thanks for your help but now i got new error like - "#1142 - TRIGGER command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'user'"

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER requires this privilege - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html. You need to grant it, or create trigger from root's account.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiter problems I reckon:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `credentials` (`UserId`,`Password`,`UserType`,`Status`) VALUES (NEW.UserId,NEW.Password,'2',NEW.Status);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Already try but getting new error like - "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$"