# Getting issue in mysql Procedures

Tags: mysql

Below is the code I have used for creating a MySQL procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllComments()
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM comment;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This procedure has been executed correctly, except when I'm trying to call procedure (`CALL GetAllComments()`) it is giving me the error below:

```
Error - #1312 - PROCEDURE test.getAllComments can't return a result set in the given context
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: may be its version bug cause on 5.3 and later version its not creating any issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2360371/161052