# Stored procedure is not working with PHP call

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't return a result set in the given context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context)

I am trying to call a basic stored procedure using PHP. But mysql produces an error like "PROCEDURE softland.getAllProducts can't return a result set in the given context".

Stored Procedure

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
 BEGIN
 SELECT *  FROM products;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

PHP code is

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("softland",$con);
$id = 1;
$result = mysql_query("call getAllProducts()");
echo $result;

if ($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<br>".$row['name'];
}
echo "Succees";
 ?>
```

Comment: Plz check the question update.. The error is "PROCEDURE softland.getAllProducts can't return a result set in the given context"

Answer (score 1):

Well, this answer is straight from the php page on [mysql_connect](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#86645):

> $this->con = mysql_connect($this->h,$this->u,$this->p,false,65536);

Which tells your mysql client to use multi-statement support (see also the mysql client constants: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags)

Comment: Thanks for your time . So please make it clear how can I solve the issue ?

Comment: I have updated the code with $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","",false,65536). But still showing the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Function GetProducts($out)
{
    $query.= "CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts() ";
    $query.= "BEGIN";
    $query.= "SELECT *  FROM products;";
    $query.= "END";
    return $query;
}
```

In the code put this,

```
$result = mysql_query(GetProducts());
```

Hope that works !!

Comment: what is $out in the function GetProducts($out)?

Comment: I have posted few questions here , but did not get answers for that. I am really depressed :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using the old mysql functions instead of the [newer mysqli library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Try following the examples on [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php).