# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ambot\database.php on line 6

Tags: stored-procedures, php

I have PHP code that calls stored procedures from a database.

```
<?php
include("DataBase.php");
$sql=$mysqli_query("CALL sp()");
if( $sql === FALSE ) {
trigger_error('Query failed returning error: '. $mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
while($row=$mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $row['id'].'--'.$row['item'].'';
}
}
?>
```

DB Conection;

```
<?php
$mysqli_hostname = "localhost";
$mysqli_user = "root";
$mysqli_password = "";
$mysqli_database = "liveedit";
$bd = $mysqli_connect($mysqli_hostname, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password) 
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
$mysqli_select_db($mysqli_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
?>
```

The code returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ambot\database.php on line 6
```

What's wrong with the code? I tried to fix this one but fixing this using stored procedure in my code adds difficulties.

Comment: Your mysql_query call is encountering an error, hence why it is returning `FALSE`. See php's [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation. Are you sure your query is correct?

Comment: ive updated my post above. check the query and the error now is different. Check it out..

Comment: Are you logging in as `root` in `include("DataBase.php");`? You might want to set the `Definer` to be a little more leniant for your procedure. See the MySQL documentation on [Procedures syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: yup, the user is root. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Is this a bug in your php version? See the possibly related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. It might be a bug as @Aiias said. You can try to switch to `mysqli_*`

Comment: i think it's not. i'm using php 5.3.1 and it is latest version. everything is right here, right? My stored procedure created well, i just don't know why is this happening.

Comment: @peterm:i changed the query to $mysqli_query() but it dd not work either.

Comment: @SoonToBeRevealed I hope you changed connection code also. Did you? **All** `mysql_*` functions should be changed to their `mysqli_*` analogs. Does it give you the same error?

Comment: @peterm:here's the error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ambot\results.php on line 3.

Comment: @SoonToBeRevealed See my updated prev comment. You can't just change one function call from one extention to another. What you can do is to comment out `include("DataBase.php");` temporarily, put `mysqli_*` connection code right in here for testing purpose and see what you get. You will have to also change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine on my machine.

You can try to switch `mysqli_*` extension, at least for testing purposes. To that end change your code that way and make sure that your connection info is correct (host, username, password, database name).

```
<?php
//include("DataBase.php");

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password", "dbname");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "CALL sp()");
if( $sql === FALSE ) {
   die('Query failed returning error: '. mysqli_error());
} else {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
       {
        echo $row['id']. "<br>";
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: @SoonToBeRevealed Try my code and let see what it will tell you.