# Why am i getting this error when calling a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

This is a MySQL PHP(5.2.5) setup.

I'm doing a basic call to a procedure like so...

```
$sp = mysql_query("CALL AlmGetRecord()"); 
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sp) or die(mysql_error());
print_r($res);
```

But no matter what i do, i get this error.

**PROCEDURE AlmGetRecord can't return a result set in the given context**

I did some quick googling around, didn't find much other than it being a potential Bug in PHP. Can anyone confirm that? or tell my why this error keeps popping up?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: Could you post the contents of your stored procedure?

Comment: Please refer to this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1201668

Comment: The content of this particular one is a basic SELECT * FROM tablename;

Comment: Thanks, i'll give the pdo/mysqli a shot.

Comment: So my server does not have PDO installed for mysql. I spoke with the guy who has control over it, he said mysql_* works just fine. I had to add a few more parameters to the connection string. So now it's working. HOWEVER, i'm on your side with using PDO. I've been so used to using CMS queries, i never realized mysql_* function were deprecated. Thanks Guy!