# How to CALL a PROCEDURE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, call, procedure

I've started to examine Procedures in MySQL, but all my efforts don't work. Here is my Procedure Creation:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN a INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `id` = a;
END
```

MySQL returns O.K., no errors.

```
 DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL returns O.K., no errors.

But CALL-Statement does not work:

```
CALL test(8);
```

Returns an error:
     #1312 - PROCEDURE dbxyz.test can't return a result set in the given context

Now, I don't know what I've made wrong: a mistake in Procedure-Cration or an error in CALL-Statement.

--> ##########################

As of 6th Feb. 2014:
Today, I've tried to find out, why my Stored Procedure does not work in Query Window of phpMyAdmin. A 'SELECT *' does not work within a Stored Procedure, but a SELECT column by column does work. Here is what I have found out: Use IN and OUT as well as INTO. Example:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN a INT, OUT b VARCHAR(12), OUT c INT)
 BEGIN
   SELECT b, c
   FROM `table`
   WHERE `id` = a
   INTO b, c;
 END
```

Now, this stored Procedure is able to run in phpMyAdmin:

```
 call test(5, @result1, @result2);
 SELECT @result1, @result2
```

If you just need ONE result instad of two or more, you could also use SET - Statement. Here we are:

```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN a INT, OUT b INT)
   BEGIN
        SET b = ( SELECT b
        FROM table
        WHERE id = a );
   END
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360371/mysql-stored-procedures-not-working-with-select-basic-question) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context)?

Comment: Not really. I've set up this query in Query Window in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Well, your query looks correct.  I suspect this is a phpMyAdmin issue which sporadically appears, per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2437024/2908724). If your `CALL` works in the MySQL client or in the workbench, it is the phpMyAdmin bug.  If not, we have more information.

Comment: Today, I've tried to find out, why my Stored Procedure does not work. A 'SELECT *' does not work within a Stored Procedure, but a  
SELECT column by column does work. Here is what I have found out:

     DELIMITER //
     CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN a INT, OUT b VARCHAR(12), OUT c INT)
     BEGIN
       SELECT b, c
       FROM `table`
       WHERE `id` = a
       INTO b, c;
     END

Now I can run my Procedure:

     call test(5, @result1, @result2);
     SELECT @result1, @result2

Comment: What you need is a stored function and not procedure. The difference between the two is that a stored function returns a result while stored procedure is a function without a return result. You can pass variables that will be filled with data, as you did, but to have it work the original way you thought - you'd create a function.

Comment: @N.B.: Strictly speaking, [stored procedures do return a result set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-14), but that usage seems rare in the wild.

Comment: @Peter: Glad you got it working. The last `SELECT` in a procedure is [available to the calling environment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-14), provided you've got the right client/server connection.  I think doing this through phpMyAdmin was not giving you that "correct" connection.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

see also comment above:

> Today, I've tried to find out, why my Stored Procedure does not work.
>   A 'SELECT *' does not work within a Stored Procedure, but a SELECT
>   column by column does work. Here is what I have found out: DELIMITER
>   // CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN a INT, OUT b VARCHAR(12), OUT c INT) BEGIN
>   SELECT b, c FROM table WHERE id = a INTO b, c; END Now I can run my
>   Procedure: call test(5, @result1, @result2); SELECT @result1, @result2
>   – Peter Feb 6 '14 at 11:09