# CodeIgniter affected_rows() returns -1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some functions of insert/update in my Codeigniter project, and I check that they succeed with the function `affected_rows()`. I have tested it locally and it works perfect, but when I uploaded to my server it doesn't work anymore, it always returns -1 though in my database it DOES insert/update.

What could be my problem?

Thanks in advance (:

An example of my code:

```
$this->db->insert('permisos', $permiso);

return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
```

UPDATE 1:

I tried with `echo $this->db->affected_rows()` and it returned -1, so my statement returns `FALSE`.

I'm working with MySQL 5.6.16 and PHP  5.5.11 in development; MySQL 5.0.77 and PHP 5.2.9 in production. My Codeigniter version is 2.1.4.

UPDATE 2:

I found out what's my problem, I was using mysqli driver and apparently my server does not support it, so I changed it back to mysql and now this is working, but... I was set it to mysqli because I had troubles with some stored procedures ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200193/cant-return-a-result-set-in-the-given-context))... so... I need another workaround xD.

Somewhere I saw something like this

```
$insert = $this->db->insert('permisos', $permiso);

if($insert){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

And it seems to work (with mysqli driver) but I'm not sure what it does exactly or if it's a reliable way... Is it?

Comment: -1... Is it a negative one...?? Because the return is supposed to give a Boolean output... Try to return only the value of affected_rows viz. `return $this->db->affected_rows();`.

Comment: Probably be useful to know the difference in your development vs production environment as well.  PHP versions, etc...

Comment: `affected_rows` in CodeIgniter is often just a wrapper for the underlying implementation in PHP. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you set the right credentials for your server sql connections?

Comment: @nazim I guess, since it actually does execute my query.

Comment: Ouch! User privileges?

Comment: I've updated again (:, thanks!